# How to get twitter followers list of any username or user_id without using authKeys and accesstoken

Tags: php, jquery, postman

I am using this process using postman to get list of all followers

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/endpoint.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=example&count=20
```

and i am getting this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Sorry, that page does not exist",
      "code": 34
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you so sure that it's possible at all to get the followers without authentication?

The official site states Authentication is required
[image]